# setInterval and clearInterval through button click events

Tags: javascript, timer

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = runThis;
function runThis() {

  const txtMin = document.getElementsByClassName("min");
  const txtSec = document.getElementsByClassName("sec");

  function go() {
    setInterval(countDown, 1000);
  }

  function countDown() {
    timeNow = timeNow - 1;
    timeSec = timeNow % 60; //remainder as seconds
    timeMin = Math.round((timeNow/60) - (timeSec/60)); //minutes

    txtMin[0].innerText =
      (timeMin > 0 ? 
        (timeMin >= 10 ? `${timeMin}:` : `0${timeMin}:`)
      : "00:");

    txtSec[0].innerText =
      (timeSec > 0 ? 
        (timeSec >= 10 ? timeSec : `0${timeSec}`)
      : "00");
  }

  function stopIt() {
    let x = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    clearInterval(x);
  }

  const btnStart = document.getElementsByClassName("start");
  btnStart[0].addEventListener("click", go);

  const btnStop = document.getElementsByClassName("stop");
  btnStop[0].addEventListener("click", stopIt);
}
```

I am having trouble trying to set up setInterval and clearInterval.
2 buttons: `start` and `stop`. I want the function `go` to run when I click `start` to start the timer. That is all good. My problem is trying to stop the timer.

If I put `let x = setInterval(countDown, 1000);` outside the `stopIt()` function, it will automatically start the timer on `windows.onload` regardless of whether or not I click the `start` button but, in doing so, I can stop the timer.

If I put `let x = setInterval(countDown, 1000);` inside the `stopIt()` function like what I have here, I can start the timer whenever I want by clicking the `start` button, but now I can't stop the timer using `clearInterval()`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the ID of the interval in the "go" function in a variable outside to be canceled inside the "stopIt" function, like this:

```
window.onload = runThis;
function runThis() {
  var intervalID = null;
  const txtMin = document.getElementsByClassName("min");
  const txtSec = document.getElementsByClassName("sec");

  function go() {
    intervalID = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
  }

  function countDown() {
    timeNow = timeNow - 1;
    timeSec = timeNow % 60; //remainder as seconds
    timeMin = Math.round((timeNow/60) - (timeSec/60)); //minutes

    txtMin[0].innerText =
      (timeMin > 0 ? 
        (timeMin >= 10 ? `${timeMin}:` : `0${timeMin}:`)
      : "00:");

    txtSec[0].innerText =
      (timeSec > 0 ? 
        (timeSec >= 10 ? timeSec : `0${timeSec}`)
      : "00");
  }

  function stopIt() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }

  const btnStart = document.getElementsByClassName("start");
  btnStart[0].addEventListener("click", go);

  const btnStop = document.getElementsByClassName("stop");
  btnStop[0].addEventListener("click", stopIt);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the logic behind this? I'm asking because doing `var intervalID = setInterval(countDown, 1000);` outside the `go` function runs it automatically. Is it like a flag where I just replace it everytime I click `start` or `stop`?

Comment: The logic is simple. setInterval() returns an ID that will be used to identify that loop, so, if you start it, the variable "intervalID" gets marked, so, you can use that variable outside the functions to stop that marked interval in the stopIt() function. If you want to control that the go() and stopIt() functions behave properly, modify them to run (or stop) if the var intervalID is null or not.